# Why sealed and singleton?

Tags: class, singleton, sealed, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purpose of final and sealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450250/purpose-of-final-and-sealed)

Hi all,

When should we opt for designing a sealed class?

When should we opt for designing a singleton class?

Comment: Half of this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450250/purpose-of-final-and-sealed.  The other half is a duplicate of countless others.

Comment: I prefer dependency injection to singletons in every case I can think of.  Dependency injection promotes looser coupling, which makes your code much more unit testable and much easier to change in the future.  A singleton is basically a global variable in disguise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two unrelated uses of a class.

A singleton should be used when you know that you will have exactly one instance of the class during its execution.

A sealed class simply means that it cannot be subclassed (or inherited). I don't know when it is good situation to mark a class as sealed, so I never do.